# Row-wise backward cumulative product/multiplication for a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

I have a matrix `x`:

```
x <- matrix(1:8, nrow = 2, ncol = 4, byrow = 2)
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 1    2    3    4 
#[2,] 5    6    7    8
```

I want to get a new matrix `y`:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  24   24   12    4
#[2,] 1680 336   56    8
```

The logic is (taking the 1st row for example):

```
y[1, 1] = prod(x[1, 1:4])
y[1, 2] = prod(x[1, 2:4])
y[1, 3] = prod(x[1, 3:4])
y[1, 4] = prod(x[1, 4:4])
```

I know the `prod` function works if I want to multiply the entire row, but I can't figure out how to do the sequential multiplication I mentioned above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any additional packages:

```
ind <- ncol(x):1
t(apply(x[, ind], 1, cumprod))[, ind]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   24   24   12    4
#[2,] 1680  336   56    8
```

More efficiently with **matrixStats** package:

```
ind <- ncol(x):1
matrixStats::rowCumprods(x, cols = ind)[, ind]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   24   24   12    4
#[2,] 1680  336   56    8
```